# How to use pagination on ajax data

Tags: ajax, laravel

I want to use default pagination in laravel in view fetched by ajax function. put I get an error.

ajax function

```
public function get_products($id){
    $products = Product::where('category_id',$id)->where('is_hidden','0')->paginate(9);
    $category = Category::find($id);
    $returnHTML = view('products_ajax')->with('products', $products)->with('category', $category)->render();
    return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
}
```

returned view by ajax

```
    <h3>{{$category->name}}</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="cards">
            @foreach($products as $product)
                <div class="card" data-item-id="{{$product->id}}">
                    <img style="width:50%;" src="{{asset('storages/images/products/'.$product->image)}}">
                    <div class="card-details">
                        <p class="card-brand">{{$product->brand->name}}</p>
                        <p class="card-name" title="Food Name Here Food Name Here Food Name Here Food Name Here">
                            {{$product->code}}
                        </p>


                        <p class="card-price" hidden> {{$product->price}}</p>

                        <p hidden class="card-full-des">
                            {{strip_tags(html_entity_decode($product->description))}}
                        </p>
                        <p class="card-packing">
                            <span>{{$product->packing}}</span>
                        </p>
                        {{-- <p class="card-packing">
                            <span>Packing: 12-8 oz (225g)</span>
                        </p> --}}
                        <div class="card-foot">
                            <button class="mbtn5" onclick="CardAddToCartOrDetails(this, true)">Add to Cart</button>
                            <button class="mbtn4" onclick="CardAddToCartOrDetails(this, false)">Details</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach
                {{$products->links()}}
        </div>
</div>
```

but I get this error:

[image: error]

so, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is caused by a calling a route with a wrong method.

i.e. defining a GET route for `/users` and calling it with POST would result in this error.